# How to add rows dynamically in kendo gantt chart?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-gantt

I need to add rows to Kendo Gantt chart dynamically (somewhat like add new task). 
I am adding the new row to dataSource, but the newly added row is not reflecting in the UI. I tried refreshing the gantt chart, but no luck. Adding k-rebind works, but I do not want to go with k-rebind option.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/D5TZlsrUS9XX2nV6WOFe?p=preview

```
function injectRow() {
    $scope.myGanttOptions = ganttServices.injectRow($scope.myGanttOptions);
    console.log($scope.myGanttOptions); //$scope.myGanttOptions is having the newly injected row, but it is not seen in the UI.

    //  refreshing the gantt chart does not inject the row.(even after trying it in timeout)
    $timeout(function() {
        $('#ganttID').getKendoGantt().dataSource.read();
        $('#ganttID').getKendoGantt().refresh();
    },100);
}
```

Comment: Attaching a plunker for the reference. http://plnkr.co/edit/Vv8arAuE2Go0XGXfUJoj?p=preview

Comment: I don't understand...the plunker in your question seems to add the task just fine and the plunker in your comment is a grid example, *not* a gantt example.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link. Pls referr http://plnkr.co/edit/D5TZlsrUS9XX2nV6WOFe?p=preview

Comment: Yes. In the plunker in the question(and in your second comment), when I click the "INJECT ROW" button, I get a new "Software Engineer" item in the gantt...it looks like it is working.

Comment: It is working because I have used k-rebind. I want it to work without using k-rebind.